# Retrieve Username of a logged in user in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#

i have developed a windows based application and SQL Server 2008 as a back end, i have a log in form, is it possible to retrieve that username that i logged in by on another form?any help please? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your two forms are in different process? 
If so, maybe you need to use some inter-process communication mechanism to get the username.

Comment: when i log in the log in form will hide and the other form shows up.

Comment: the two forms are in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the name of the currently logged in user by inspecting the environment variable `USERNAME`. However it is possible that the process could be running under some other users credentials.

If all you want however is to do something with those credentials, you can use the `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` or `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`.

Comment: is it for Web application?mine is windows application remember.

Comment: @Shamal, that would depend on your specific situation. There are no general practices that I'm aware of.

Comment: My Question is clear, i have two forms 1. Log in form, 2. is the Main form, i need to have the logged in user on the main form when i log in.

Comment: Since the log-in form and the main belong to your own application you should be able to store the user name in a variable that your main form has access to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried this but unsuccessful.i solve the username in a variable but when i press log in button log in form will hide and the main form will show up but no username is retrieved.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx